# Troubleshooting Terraform Code for sending notifications to sns topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-sns

I'm currently building out terraform code that allows s3 buckets to send notifications to an sns topic once an object has been created.

Here's a code snippet:

```
// Creates SNS Topic
resource "aws_sns_topic" "topic" {
  name = "topic-name"
}

//Creates Policy thats allows s3 bucket to publish data
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "iam_policy" {
    statement {
      effect = "Allow"
      actions = [
        "SNS:Publish"
      ]
      resources = [
        aws_sns_topic.topic.arn
      ]
    } 
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "topic_policy" {
    arn = aws_sns_topic.topic.arn
    policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.iam_policy.json
  
}

// This sent alerts to sns topic when there's an object created in S3 bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
    bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3-bucket.id
    topic {
      topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.topic.arn
      events = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
      
    }
  
}
```

The terraform code creates all of the infrastructure, but when it's time to create the policy I receive this error.

```
aws_sns_topic_policy.topic_policy: Creating...
 aws_sns_topic_policy.topic_policy: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
 aws_sns_topic_policy.topic_policy: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
 aws_sns_topic_policy.topic_policy: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
 aws_sns_topic_policy.topic_policy: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
 aws_sns_topic_policy.topic_policy: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
 aws_sns_topic_policy.topic_policy: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]
 aws_sns_topic_policy.topic_policy: Still creating... [1m10s elapsed]
 aws_sns_topic_policy.topic_policy: Still creating... [1m20s elapsed]
 aws_sns_topic_policy.topic_policy: Still creating... [1m30s elapsed]
 aws_sns_topic_policy.topic_policy: Still creating... [1m40s elapsed]
 aws_sns_topic_policy.topic_policy: Still creating... [1m50s elapsed]

│ Error: setting SNS Topic (arn:aws:sns:<REGION>:<ACCOUNTID>:topic-name) attribute (Policy): InvalidParameter: Invalid parameter: Policy Error: null
│       status code: 400, request id:
│ 
│   on sns.tf line 19, in resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "topic_policy":
│   19: resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "topic_policy" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: putting S3 Bucket Notification Configuration: InvalidArgument: Unable to validate the following destination configurations
│       status code: 400, request id: , host id:
│ 
│   on sns.tf line 26, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification":
│   26: resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
```

I've tried using this format of the sns topic policy, with same error.

```
// Creates SNS Topic
resource "aws_sns_topic" "topic" {
  name = "topic-name"
  
  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sns:Publish",
      "Resource": "${aws_sns_topic.topic.arn}",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.s3-bucket.id}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

// This sends alerts to sns topic when there's an object created in S3 bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3-bucket.id
  topic {
    topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.topic.arn
    events     = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work with the following policy doc:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "iam_policy" {
  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["SNS:Publish"]
    resources = [aws_sns_topic.topic.arn]
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["s3.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

All I added was the `principals` section, that is all.

Full code here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/blob/master/TerraForm/sns/main.tf